# Помогите сделать сообщение вложением embed - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я работаю над ботом для Discord с помощью модуля для Python - Discord.py.
У меня появилась задача сделать сообщение от бота, вложением. Я создал команду `help` и попробовал в ней создать простой `embed` с заголовком, вот код моей команды:

```
bot.remove_command('help')
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = 'Помощь')
    await ctx.send( embed = embed )
```

Но в момент запуска моего бота, в консоли вышла ошибка -

```
    await ctx.send( embed = embed )
                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Я не понимаю что она означает, помогите мне с этим разобраться.
Я пишу бота типа `bot`, с префиксом `!`. У меня установлен Python 3.7.0.

**P.S.** Решено: Евгений, который дал ответ ниже был прав. Дело было в табуляции. Перед ключевыми строками `await ctx.send( embed = embed )` и `embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = 'Помощь')` стояли четыре пробела, после того как я поставил один таб перед этими строками проблема решилась.

Comment: Ошибка отступов. Возможно, вы неправильно их расставили, а возможно - использовали табуляции вперемешку с пробелами. Выберите единый тип табуляции и используйте его во всём проекте. В любом текстовом редакторе есть меню "Заменить" (или "Поиск и замена"). Замените все табуляции на 4 пробела (или 4 пробела на табуляцию, как удобнее).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён, проблема была в табуляции, вместо четырёх пробелов должен стоять отступ клавишей Tab.

Comment: Наоборот, должны использоваться 4 пробела для отступов, а не символ табуляции